# Django GEOSException at /

Tags: python-3.x, django, gis, geo, geodjango

Recently when I tried to create a Polygon instance in Django (version 3.1) I got this error:

GEOSException at /
Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r".

Here's my coordinates that I'm using:

```
Polygon((51.558994, -0.16349), (51.552505, -0.121468), (51.527564, -0.179695), (51.527564, -0.179695))
```

These coordinates are just a sample.
I'm using Polygon coordinates from the leaflet, but when I try to create django.contrib.gis.geos.polygon.Polygon Instance, I get that error.

Do have any idea or approach to store received coordinate from leaflet to polygon in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polygon first and last coordinate should be identical ( linear ring )